# Can I apply for a student visa in Italy?

Tags: italy, student-visa, mexican-citizens

I am a Mexican student that will do an exchange to Italy.

Can I apply for a student visa when I am in Italy?

Applying for it in Mexico will result in a delay of my arrival.

Comment: You've already posted this on Travel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.esteri.it/mae/en/ministero/servizi/sportello_info/domandefrequenti/visto_per_italia/#4) it will need to be submitted to "Italian diplomatic-consular post", which is consulate or an embassy:

> **Where do I submit my visa application and who needs to submit an application?**
>
> The organisation responsible for issuing visas issued by Italy is the Italian diplomatic-consular post in your place of habitual residence or origin. This is the only organisation authorised to evaluate and verify that you, as a foreign national, meet the requirements to obtain a visa.
>
> **Uniform Schengen Visas.** For Uniform Schengen Visas (both for transit and for short stays), if Italy is not your only or principal destination, you should submit your visa application to the diplomatic-consular post of the Schengen country that is your main destination.
>
> If it is not possible to establish which country is your main destination (for example if you are making a journey with stays in different Schengen countries), the diplomatic-consular post of the first Schengen country you plan to enter will be responsible for issuing the visa.
>
> If your destination Schengen country does not have a diplomatic-consular post in your country of residence, the Schengen visa can be issued by the diplomatic-consular post of another Schengen country that represents your destination country.
>
> **National visas.** It is the diplomatic-consular post of the Schengen state that will be your long-stay destination that is responsible for issuing your national visa.
>
> For national visas, there are no agreements in place for one country to represent, and issue visas on behalf of, another country in a foreign national’s country of residence.
>
> You must submit your visa application in person to the appropriate consular office, usually by appointment.